# Multiple DOMContentLoaded event not working

Tags: javascript, html

Im having trouble with two pieces of javascript in that only the last one added seems to be working. I suspect it has something to do with the DOMContentLoaded event causing a bit of havoc. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<div id="previewWidget1"></div>
<div id="previewWidget2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.connectedcommunity.org/widgetscripts/widgets/hlwidgetcommon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.connectedcommunity.org/widgetscripts/widgets/latestDiscussion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
hl.latestDiscussion('previewWidget1', {
    discussionKey:'xxx',
    maxToRetrieve:'3',
    subjectLength:'50',
    contentLength:'160',
    moreUrl:'xxx',
    showLoginStatus:'1',
    loginUrl:'xxx',
    domainUrl:'xxx',
    cbUseBioBubble:'0',
    includeStaff:'1',
    HLIAMKey:'xxx'
});
});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
hl.latestDiscussion('previewWidget2', {
    discussionKey:'xxx',
    maxToRetrieve:'3',
    subjectLength:'50',
    contentLength:'160',
    moreUrl:'xxx',
    showLoginStatus:'1',
    loginUrl:'xxx',
    domainUrl:'xxx',
    cbUseBioBubble:'0',
    includeStaff:'1',
    HLIAMKey:'xxx'
 });
});
```

Comment: Debug your code by adding breakpoints.

Comment: What do you mean by `only the last one added` ? Do you see any script errors in your dev tools console ? If you're unsure about DOMContentLoaded event handlers, you can put an alert in both these functions and see if both are coming or not. Ideally they should come. One more question, can't you club your hl.latestDiscussion() calls in to a single event listener function ? Any reason for separate functions ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have tried adding both hl.latestDiscussion's under the one event but it doesn't help.